# Date in Google App Scrip (Make de calculation using 2 Date and return the numer of da days)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I just want to make a simple calculation using 2 Dates.

Ex: in the Sheet Cell `A1 = 10/11/2021` and cell `A2 = 12/11/2021`

The function takes the date and calculation (10/11/2021 - 12/11/2021) and returns in Cell A3 the number 2.

This sounds very easy, but I can't do this probably because of the format of the Date that I can't change.

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: This might be about overkill but you could check out how  moment.js handles  Dates under the hood. These libraries are battle-tested so you know the code is solid =)

ref: https://momentjs.com/guides/

Answer (score 0):

When you do calculation on the `date` objects, they would be converted into milliseconds, so the following would give you the difference in days:

```js
  const diff = (d2 - d1) / 1000*60*60*24;
```